# Birthdate with Month And Date only In Ascending Order

Tags: php, mysql

I have A column Birthdate in mysql table in yyyy-mm-dd format

I want to show only month and date in ascending format.

i have tried it as follows...

```
 SELECT * FROM table_name Order by birthdate ASC
```

and in display area used code as follows -

```
=date("F d ",strtotime($data["birthdate"]))
```

Now It Is Showing Ascending Order, but as years are different for each user..it is shoing results as :

```
January 02,
January 31,
February 06,
March 22,
December 23,
March 27,
June 13,
January 23....
```

(Here It is example...but it is showing ascending but as years are different, it is showing for each year in ascending order)

I want it as All January Dates, Then February...and so on...

Comment: @Hardy It isn't, and in any case, that's not a reason!

Comment: dr manish joshi - Dates are being stored with a date data type, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `DAYOFYEAR()` to sort:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` ORDER BY DAYOFYEAR(`birthdate`) ASC
```

`DAYOFYEAR` gives a number between `1` and `366`.

Answer (score 0):

try below query,

```
SELECT * FROM table_name Order by DATENAME(month, birthdate) ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(birthdate,'%M %d')
```